# Email Notification when a new git repository is created

Tags: linux, shell, github, github-api

I have prepared a shell script for repository creation in GitHub, but when ever a new repository is created I want to check it manually.

Is there any script that will send me an email notification when a new repository is created in GitHub.

Comment: You don't need a script. Just subscribe to this notification at github.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, Its related to organization who ever created a new repo in my organization they need to get an email that a repo has created

Comment: I automatically get an email whenever someone in my organization creates a new repo. I can't find a setting where I enabled it, so I think it's the default.